# How to install ruby?

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I am pretty new to ruby world and I don't know about installing it. Viewing methods from blogs with google search but feeling confuse.

Could somebody help me to setup ruby in my Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run these commands on terminal to install Ruby 2.0.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
```

To check the ruby version,run this

```
ruby2.0 --version
```

Comment: my friend , why didn't you noticed me earlier ?