# How to remove Ruby 1.9.1 keeping Ruby 2.0.0?

Tags: apt, 14.04, ruby

I have Ruby 2.0.0 installed on Ununtu 14.04 but I can't remove Ruby 1.9.1. I replaced the /usr/bin/ruby symbolic link to ruby2.0.0, but hhen installing new gems I always get pointed to Ruby 1.9.1.

How can I definitely switch to Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge ruby ruby1.9.1`. Note that 1.9.1 is still the default, and there may be programs using this version.

Comment: ruby2.0 is removed too:

The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libruby1.9.1* libruby2.0* ruby* ruby1.9.1* ruby2.0* rubygems-integration*

Comment: Well, that's a wrench I didn't see coming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Ruby, the basic dependency structure goes like this:

1. `ruby` (which would ideally be a metapackage that points to the default version) depends on `ruby1.9.1`
2. `ruby2.0` depends on `ruby`

I'm not sure why they did this, or why they removed the ability to use alternatives here, but if you want to force the use of Ruby 2.0, then one non-invasive way to do this is to create symlinks to the 2.0 binaries. The snippet below will create symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`.

```
for i in erb gem irb rdoc ri ruby testrb; do
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/$i''2.0 /usr/local/bin/$i
done
```

Ruby 1.9.1 is still accessible by appending `1.9.1` to the binary name (for example, `gem1.9.1`).

Comment: Thank's! I created a symlink but I had problems with gem. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to hand-maintaining multiple symlinks, I suggest using `update-alternatives`. In [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452243/install-ruby-2-0-without-ruby-switch/611442#611442), I provided a script to handle all binaries and man pages in ruby versions 1.9.1 and 2.0 (as currently found in my 14.04 system), though the script is easily extended to different versions.